# Can't Connect to Players

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am playing Dark Souls 2 for Xbox 360 and I have Xbox Live, but when I try invading anyone, or leave a summon sign nothing ever happens! I've turned on cross region play and still nothing. My internet connection is perfect. What can I do to get better match making?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider when approaching online play in the Dark Souls games:

- When first initiating online play, you send out a short-range ping, looking for players/showing yourself to players. Over time, the range increases, connecting to more and more players.
- In Dark Souls 1, the range of players you could connect with was restricted to your Soul Level. In Dark Souls 2, this is dependant on your *[Soul Memory](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Soul+Memory)*. Therefore effectively allowing a SL10 and a SL100 to match up, depending on how terribly the SL10 player is performing.

  - This can also be a restriction on who you can connect with in a bad way. For example, there are some areas that have general Soul Memory Levels. If you are outside of this range, it will be harder to find players to connect to. [Here is a list of general Soul Memory levels per area](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Online#Online-Level%20To%20Location:%20Summoning%20Comparison) (NG Only)
- There are items that can affect the range of players you can connect with, namely the use of the [Small White Soapstone](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Small+White+Sign+Soapstone) vs the [Large White Soapstone](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/White+Sign+Soapstone), and the [Name Engraved Ring](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Name-engraved+Ring). [Here is a small app](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Summon+Range+Calculator) you can use to calculate who you can connect with, depending on your soul level, using these items.
- The last thing you might want to consider is your firewall settings. It is possible that your firewall is blocking your multiplayer settings. [Here is a list of ports to open](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Online#Online-Online%20Play%20Issues), depending on the console you are using.

In all honesty, it's most likely just due to a Soul Memory mis-match. I personally have a lot of issues connecting with other players in the Black Gulch, to fight The Rotten, as it's usually either the first, or last boss that I fight (of the 4 Great Ones).

Comment: @Spit2703 if I have answered your question, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the "tick" icon to the left

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of factors that my contribute to this other than a 'good' internet connection.

There are a number of items that make your summon range larger so more people may be able to summon you in or be invaded.  Rings like the Engraved Named Ring increase your summon range and paired with a small white soap stone, increases even more.

What's more, you need to consider which summon tier you are in and what other tiers you will be able to summon/invade.

Check out the [summon range on the wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Summon+Range+Calculator) to find where you are and see if equipping an item or using an item can help you find other players.