# Dark Souls 2 coop/invading problem

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was playing Dark Souls II on my pc a lot. After about 200 hours of ingame time I found that I cant summon or invade anybody. I tried new characters and reinstalling but it didn't help. So any tips, and reasons. P.S. I didn't used any cheats.

Comment: Can you provide more info. What soul level is your character? What did you try to do? Where? How much soul memory do you have?

Comment: Different soul levels. From 4k to 2,5 kk. Iron keep, Aldias keep, shrine of Amana, forest of giants, lost bastille

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204146/cant-connect-to-players)

Comment: Can you summon any npc's?

Comment: Yes, I can. And I'm absolutely sure that problem isnt SM.

Comment: This might sound stupid but are you sure you don't have the Name-engraved Ring equipped?

Comment: I dont use it, but tried to summon anybody with it too.

Comment: Have you checked the ports in your firewall? Sometimes that can block the outgoing connections

Comment: @666nordless666 A few Questions: Can you see any Signs on the ground ? If not are you in Human from ? In wich covenant are you ? If you can see Signs and you whant to summon someone how long dose it take to show the error ?

Comment: I just dont c summon signs. I wrought that i tried different characters, so it cant be humanity or covenant problem

Comment: I had this problem once, after joining and leaving the Covenant (of Champions?). Using the Bone of Order item in my inventory was enough to reconnect my character. I doubt this works for OP, but it may for others.

Comment: Are you ever summoned if you use the soapstones?

Comment: Very, very rarely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the question [I linked above in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204146/cant-connect-to-players), there are several things to consider when attempting to determine why you are unable to summon/be invaded.

**1. You are offline.**

This is highly unlikely, but it's still a possibility. Just keep an eye on your connection when you want to summon someone, and make sure you are not offline.

**2. Your ports are blocked.**

This is the more likely situation. You may be online, but your ports aren't open, therefore your firewall is blocking your connection with the rest of the online community. [Here is a relevant list of ports to open](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Online#Online-Online%20Play%20Issues)

**3. It's a Soul Memory mismatch**

You said that you believe this is unlikely, however you also stated that you *can* be summoned, though only rarely. [Here is a list of general Soul Memory levels per area](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Online#Online-Level%20To%20Location:%20Summoning%20Comparison), though this is just a guideline.

**4. You're in the CoC**

Again, unlikely. The Covenant of Champions does block coop summoning capability, but it should also block NPC summons as well, *and* it should also *increase* your likelihood of being invaded. From what you have reported, this doesn't match up. Nevertheless, you can still easily check. If you are in the CoC, next to your stat bars (health and endurance) you should see this icon.

[image]

If you are in this covenant, you can leave by talking to [Shalquoir](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Sweet_Shalquoir)

**5. You have been disconnected from online play, as punishments for d/c while being invaded.**

Again, the effects are similar to CoC - removing coop summoning, *increased* chance of invasion. I'm not sure if this affects NPC summoning however. To fix this, there is an item called the "Bone of Order". If you *can* use this item, this is most likely the case, as you can only use it once you have been "punished".

You can gain additional [Bones of Order](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bone+of+Order) in NG+ from the Falconer enemies in Things Betwixt.

I hope you find something to solve your problem!

Comment: Ty, i'll check my firewall :3

Comment: @666nordless666 any news?