# Constant disconnects, playing online impossible

Tags: pc, dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I've got a huge problem with my Dark Souls 2 SOTFS PC version. It is impossible for me to play online. I get disconnected quite often, but it's always different. Sometimes I get disconnected every 10 minutes, yesterday I was was online for hours and I got disconnected when I tried to summon somebody.

Summoning doesn't work in 99% of all cases for various reasons and as I already mentioned I also get disconnected quite often when I try to summon somebody. Some rare times when summoning worked (in this example before the pursuer's boss fight) I could interact with the phantom(s), they used emotes etc. but when I entered the boss room they didn't come in through the mist and when I died I did not respawn or anything. I, as a non-present spectator, stayed in the boss room and saw the boss go back to its initial position and could only move the camera and watch. Only killing the task and restarting got me out of that. And this strange phenomenon occured *every single time* I succeeded in summoning someone (and died).

Another weird thing is when I try to make bell keeper PvP (at Belfry Luna). If I use my ring and invade others as a grey phantom (in case this works at all and I'm not disconnected before or while waiting) it's extremely laggy and by extremely I mean that I can backstab or hit the host and he doesn't lose any TP. And in the next moment, when he's at the other end of the room, I get backstabbed by him and suddenly teleport to him. It's not possible to fight this way.

I also tried helping as a white phantom. There it is the case that I don't deal damage to anything and I mostly get kicked by the host as I don't know what the hell's going on. From his point of view I'm probably hitting the air or anything.

My internet connection is great, it works perfectly fine in every other game and everything else so that cannot be the problem. I can also paste a speedtest later if anybody wants proof. 
Opening the ports didn't change a thing. I also already had huge connectivity issues in DS.
I don't know what to do anymore, I really want to do PvP and help others or sometimes get help from others. And I don't want to get disconnected over and over again. I'm sorry about the wall of text, but I feel like it is necessary to explain my problem as detailled as possible.

I hope someone can help me, I'm going crazy over this.

**EDIT**: Retried Port Forwarding, did not fix anything again.

Comment: I feel you. The biggest problem for me is the initial connect. It takes 5-10 times until I can connect to the server (Xbox One). All other online games I play (PC + Xbox One) work perfectly fine. I'd guess it's a serverside issue.

Comment: The initial connect works fine for me, but everything else just doesn't. Hopefully it's not serverside, because that way I can probably never change anything about that.

Comment: I'd have a look into your ports/firewall settings. [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204146/cant-connect-to-players), [also related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204182/dark-souls-2-coop-invading-problem).

Comment: As I mentioned above I have already opened all necessary ports and nothing changed. Or what do you specifically mean by 'having a look'? Thanks for the related question, I'll check if it's useful when I'm at home.

Comment: if you have tried everything and nothing works. your internet is great, and all other games work splendidly... then it is just something happening on dark souls side. bandai's side? i cant remember who does DS... have you contacted the developers support side of things? Usually never helps but you never know. Before you came here, did you google? if so, were many other people having this issue?

Comment: So now that nothing could actually help me I contacted Bandai Namco support (just sent the mail). I'll keep you informed. But anyway, thank you very much for all the tips you gave me and everything! I just wish it would have fixed my problems

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're losing packets here, but I would suggest that you try port forwarding anyway. You can find referenced guides [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/251ly0/improving_ds2_multiplayer_matchmaking_with_port/) and [here](http://forums.bandainamcogames.com/showthread.php?486-quot-Summoning-canceled-unable-to-join-multiplayer-session-quot-quot-Summoning-failed-Timed-Out-quot).

If you don't know how to do that, what you want to do is go to [Portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm) then find your router. There will be an ad, but you can close it in the top right corner. You can probably just use the default config using the link found in the top paragraph of the page, generically seen below

> If you do not see the program you are forwarding ports for, you can try checking out our [Default Guide](http://linkgoeshere) for this router, which is a generic guide that should help you get through the basics of getting an open port on your X

Then you want to follow the instructions for that specific router to allow the following ports:

> ```
> UDP 27000 to 27030
> TCP 27014 to 27050
> UDP 3478 to 3479
> UDP 4379 to 4380
> TCP 3478 to 3480
> TCP 5223
> TCP 8080
> TCP 50000 to 50100
> UDP 50000 to 50100
> UDP 3458
> ```

Once all of these ports have been forwarded, you should notice an improvement in connection quality with other Dark Souls 2 players. If not, you could also try the more complete list of ports in the original posts of either link at the top of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but I have already forwarded my ports, which didn't change anything /:

Comment: If it isn't entirely unrealistic, try using a different router and PvP with it. In fact, if you're on a wired connection try connecting directly to your modem, if you have one, and see if online play quality improves.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3991/m2iynhps_png.htm) what it looks like in my port forwarding configurations. I guess that should be right, I'll try now

Comment: Nope, does not change anything :(

Comment: I dunno what to say, then. Something has to be causing it though.

Comment: I have now turned off my firewall completely and it seems to have improved. I can connect to other players, help them, invade them and everything, but I still get disconnected very very often. Right now it happened after every invade or even while trying to invade the first time in this session.

Comment: @Lunaetic That's probably the issue. Your firewall is blocking it. If you say you have opened the ports in your firewall just double check, make sure you have both the incoming and outgoing rules set up correctly with the correct ports opened.

Comment: Okay, I'll check everything later. Do you know where I can find out about all rules that should be there? Oh and it still is the case that the disconnects occur, but at least it is somehow possible to do something online. Just a little annoying that I have to restart all the time.

Comment: @Lunaetic Follow the links I provided in my above comment (on the original question). These will provide you with the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough case, because the symptoms do not point to one cause.

For starters, you want to rule out any of your equipment causing problems.  You want to setup a "direct" internet connection.  If possible, direct from modem to computer is the best, but almost no providers do this anymore.

Next best is to set up your computer as the "DMZ" target.  This basically means anything pointed to your external IP goes to your computer.  Do NOT leave your router in this mode, because your computer will probably get hacked.

If this "solves" the problem, great.  The problem is with your equipment.  You can at least fix it.

If the problem persists, then the problem is beyond your network.  You'll have to call your ISP and... well, quite frankly YMMV by a LOT at this point.